# prevent loading a ajax page the second time?

Tags: jqtouch

I'm doing an app with jquery and jqtouch.

The problem I get is that if I click a menulink and load a page and then click the same link again it loads the page again and then I can't click any other links, they stop working.

I load all my pages as separate ajax pages, and the pages are .asp pages that gets it content from the database.
So I need to set cacheGetRequests to false in the jqtouch.js file otherwise the new content isn't visible, than it just loads the page from the memory.

If I set cacheGetRequests to true then when I click a link it loads the page and if I click again, then it doesn't load the page again, and all other links work as they should.
This is how it should work, but it doesn't if I set cacheGetRequests to false.

So I guess that I have to prevent loading of a page that already has been loaded?

I bind all my pages with this code, and I find the below if (!$(this).data('loaded')) code in the jqtouch examples that I tried with, but I can't get it right.

```
$(this).bind('pageInserted', function(event, info) {

  //if (!$(this).data('loaded')) {

//this is for the iscroll script to work
  var scroller = info.page[0].querySelector(".scrollerwrapper"); 
  if (scroller) {   
   scroller.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px' ;    
   setTimeout(function () {
    myScroll = new iScroll(scroller, {
     hScrollbar: false,
     vScrollbar: false,
     checkDOMChange:false,          
    });
   myScroll.refresh();
   }, 100);  
  }

      //$(this).parent().data('loaded', true); 
  //}

 });
```